# Function has_custom_logo when used in Customizer

Tags: theme-customizer, logo

I'm attempting to integrate the `custom-logo` functionality introduced in 4.5 and I'm running into some issues with the Customizer interface.

I'm checking `has_custom_logo` and, if it's false, I'm providing a text version of the site name and description as a fallback. It works perfectly fine when you add a custom logo. However, when you "Remove" it, it appears `has_custom_logo` still returns `true`.

Example:

```
if ( function_exists( 'the_custom_logo' ) && has_custom_logo() ) {
    the_custom_logo();
} else {
    echo 'Fallback';
}
```

Anyone else had any luck with something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it around the wrong way `has_custom_logo()` will return false if there is no logo.
`function_exists( 'the_custom_logo' )` however will return true if you are using a version of Wordpress that support this function.

So if you seperate your if statement like below it will work.

```
if( function_exists( 'the_custom_logo' ) ) {
    if(has_custom_logo()) {
        the_custom_logo();
    } else {
        echo "No logo";
    }
}
```

Comment: What will happen here if the function doesn't exists - no fallback? Regarding the logic in the original question, it sounds like you're talking about the case `A || B`  but not  `A && B`? In general `A && B` is only true if both `A` and `B` are true. So `function_exists( 'the_custom_logo' ) && has_custom_logo()` is true if only both are true.

Comment: I ended up using `get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo', false )` instead of `the_custom_logo()` because I feel like it's closer to the original functionality of my function prior to 4.5. I do however agree that I should have started out checking for support with `function_exists( 'the_custom_logo' )` separately. I was just trying to be efficient.

Answer (score 2):

I used similar code to that in the question, using an image as a fallback, and works fine. Below 4.5 displays the fallback image and above 4.5 displays the custom logo, if one is set. If there is no custom logo set or it is removed, it displays the fallback image.

```
<?php if ( function_exists( 'the_custom_logo' ) && has_custom_logo() ) : ?>
    <?php the_custom_logo(); ?>
<?php else : ?> 
    <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home" title="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo.png" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>" width="100" height="50" /></a></h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```